# Some of are my attributes are set as not defined when I try to use classes ad inheritance

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance

When I try to run this code:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age, height):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}, Age: {}, Height: {}".format(self.name, self.age, self.height)

    def get_older(years):
        self.age += years

class Worker(Person): 

    def __init__(self, name, age, height, salary):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(name, age, height)
        self.salary = salary 

    def calc_yearly_salary(self):
        return salary * 12

worker1 = Worker('Henry', 42, 178, 3350)
print(worker1)
print(worker1.calc_yearly_salary())
```

It doesn´t recognize the attribute salary giving me the following error saying that "salary" is not defined:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Jorge87/Desktop/Master Tema 1.5/inheritance_practice.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/Jorge87/Desktop/Master Tema 1.5')
Name: Henry, Age: 42, Height: 178
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-11-07b76e08cf24>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Jorge87/Desktop/Master Tema 1.5/inheritance_practice.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/Jorge87/Desktop/Master Tema 1.5')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 
827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 
110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Jorge87/Desktop/Master Tema 1.5/inheritance_practice.py", line 32, in <module>
print(worker1.calc_yearly_salary())

File "C:/Users/Jorge87/Desktop/Master Tema 1.5/inheritance_practice.py", line 28, in 
calc_yearly_salary
return salary * 12

NameError: name 'salary' is not defined
```

What is wrong with my code? Also, it doesn´t seem to recognize the attribute "years" in the defined variable "get_older(years)"

Comment: Use this `self.salary*2`.

Comment: You forgot `self` before `salary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Worker` class, you need to refer to the `salary` attribute as `self.salary` instead of just `salary`.

```
def calc_yearly_salary(self):
    return self.salary * 12
```